# ASP.Net Login Page with MySQL

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone spot the error in this? I'm trying to create a simple login page (asp.net vb) that does a count on a mysql table. When i type anything in it logs me in even if the details do not match. I believe it'll be the case statement that's wrong but any help would be appreciated!

```
Protected Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim userId As Integer = -1
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn").ConnectionString
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
        Using uscmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUser WHERE UName = ?@Username AND Pword = ?@Password", con)
            uscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName)
            uscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password)
            Using uuda As New MySqlDataAdapter(uscmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
                uuda.Fill(ds)
                userId = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString()
            End Using

        End Using
        Select Case userId
            Case -1
                Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
                Exit Select
            Case -2
                Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated."
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet)
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query "*SELECT COUNT()...*" will always return 1 record.  After execute the query, you make an assignment

```
userId = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString()
```

So the value of *userId* will be always 1. So it always run into CASE ELSE of the CASE statement. That's why whatever you type, it logs you in even if the details do not match.

To check the username and password have been registered or not, you could update your code like following

```
Protected Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim userCount As Integer = -1
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn").ConnectionString
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
        Using uscmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUser WHERE UName = ?@Username AND Pword = ?@Password", con)
            uscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName)
            uscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password)
            Using uuda As New MySqlDataAdapter(uscmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
                uuda.Fill(ds)
                Integer.TryParse(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0), userCount) 
            End Using

        End Using

        If userCount > 0 Then
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet)                  
        Else
            Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
        End If

    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah right - i thought it would be something like that. Can you offer any type of fix to my code for this? Some kind of workaround? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just validate the user and pass back if its activated? Just FYI Rows.Count will never be < 0 your current code will never return anything other than the Case Else.